# How do I find the Fisher Information of the function $f(x \mid \lambda) = \lambda x^{\lambda - 1}$?

Tags: fisher-information

I have the following function:
$$f(x \mid \lambda) = \lambda x^{\lambda - 1} \quad \text{where} \lambda \in [0, 1]\,.$$

How do I find the Fisher information for this function?

Comment: Please define the domain of $x$.

Comment: This looks like bookwork. Is this for some class/subject/exam revision/textbook exercise etc? Please double check your definition of $f$ carefully, including the domain of $\lambda$ as well as the unstated domain for $x$.

Answer (score 2):

As suggested before the Beta trick is a neat way of solving this problem, but you have to know recurrence properties of [trigamma functions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trigamma_function). Also, this is probably your homework, I am not the homework police so here you go....

$f(x\mid\lambda)=\lambda x^{\lambda-1}$

$l=\log f(x\mid\lambda)=\log\lambda+(\lambda-1) \log x$

$\frac{\partial l}{\partial \lambda}=\frac{1}{\lambda}+\log x\quad\text{and}\quad \frac{\partial^2 l}{\partial \lambda^2}=-\frac{1}{\lambda^2}$

$\mathbb{E}\left[-\frac{\partial^2 l}{\partial \lambda^2}\mid \lambda\right]=\frac{1}{\lambda^2}$

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you mean that $x$ is on the (open) unit interval, the distribution is a special case of the [Beta distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_distribution).

The [Fisher information](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_distribution#Two_parameters) for the more general two parameter beta case seems at least potentially doable.

So to begin with, you might take the [negative of the second derivative of the log-likelihood](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher_information#Definition) with respect to $\lambda$ and try to find the expectation of that quantity, and see if you can do it the 'standard' way.

If you run into difficulty, you'll need to explain where that difficulty lies so that we can give specific guidance (i.e. *show what you tried and where things went wrong*).